# How can i send and set datatable using an external javascript method

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core

I have a datatable which contains in the first cell of each row a checkbox.I want to send an array of indexes to an external js function and check the checkboxes at the corresponding indexes.
E.g:
input : `[0,2]`
datatable:

```
chk  x x     (i want this chk to get checked)
chk  x x
chk  x x      (this chk to get checked also)
chk  x x
```

I want to check the checkboxes (chk) at row with index 0 and 2

**View**:

```
  @using Newtonsoft.Json
    @model IEnumerable<AdminMVC.Models.Location>


     <html>
    <head>
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="~/js/tbinit.js"></script>
    <script>    
             $(document).ready(function(){

                var _story=@Html.Raw(ViewData["tstory"]);  
                var indexes=@Html.Raw(ViewData["tlocations"]); //long [] 
                var table=$("table1");
                checkLocationTable(indexes,table);
     </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <table id="table1" cellspacing="10" >
          <tr >
           <th>Select</th>
            <th >ID</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th >Name</th>
            <th>Type</th>
         </tr>
                @foreach(var elem in Model)
                {
             <tr>
                <td>
                   <input id=@(string.Format("cell{0}",elem.Id)) type="checkbox">
                </td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x=>elem.Id)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x=>elem.Name)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x=>elem.Type)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x=>elem.Description)</td>
                <td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit","Edit","Location",new{ID=elem.Id},null)</td>
                <td>@Html.ActionLink("Delete","Delete","Location",new{ID=elem.Id},null)</td>
             </tr>
             }
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

**/wwwroot/js/tbinit.js**

```
function checkLocationTable (indexArray,locTable){
              $(locTable).each(function(index){
                if($.inArray(index,indexArray))
                {
                    $(this).find("td:eq(0)").prop("checked",true);
                }
            });
        }
```

Also do i have to send the HTML element as a parameter to the external function (in my case the datatable element?).If so how can i use `.each` method with a variable as selector?

```
$(locTable).each(function(index){...});  //locTable being the parameter of function
```

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I added the complete view and function already.